# shouldChangeCharactersInRange returns second character from UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im using shouldChangeCharactersInRange on my class to capture UITextField in uitableview.

problem is its not getting the first entered value and start from second one.

if i input "123" it only shows "12"

this is my code :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

    UITextField *utx = (UITextField *) textField;

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)utx.superview.superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    UITextField *utxtest = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20];

    NSLog(@"utxtest %@", utxtest.text);
       NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARECTERS] invertedSet];

        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        return [string isEqualToString:filtered];

    return YES;
}
```

and in my tableview :

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UITextField * utxtest = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20];
    utxtest = self;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: When you say that instead of '123' it shows '23', where is that? in the NSLog statement or in the UITableViewCell?

Comment: its in nslog output "utxtest 23"

Comment: What does it show if you NSLog the utx variable?

Comment: this is the output : <UITextField: 0x78966600; frame = (194 47; 71.5 30); text = '12'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 20; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7877e040>; layer = <CALayer: 0x789665d0>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested with UITextField and place NSLog on shouldChangeCharactersInRange as what you did. With input "123", nslog display "12", not "23" as you said.

So firstly, re-check your result. If it's still be "23", I have no idea about it

If it is "12", I think the problem is you place your NSLog on **shouldChangeCharactersInRange** which takes responsibility for input text validation. Textfield is only assigned new value just **AFTER** this method return YES . If return NO, the value wont change. And ofcourse, while you're still in the middle of the method, the textfield.text still returns the old value.

Comment: thanks a lot , i fixed it , ur right . that was a typo and the result is "12" instead of "23". so is there any way that i can capture the full inserted text inside shouldChangeCharactersInRange ?

Comment: I have no XCode here to test but you can try NSString *tmpNewValue =  [utxtest.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]; // string here is value of replacementString. Remember you should just get the new temp value, do not change value of utxTest in this method, it can cause side effect